# "npm err! missing script: start npm err!" in generating Angular app with Hyperledger composer

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, hyperledger-composer, package.json, npm-start

I have followed the developer docs at "https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/developer-tutorial.html" and I have been stuck at the last command "npm start" giving the error stated in the title.
".

[This is my package.json script file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9PJy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The command "npm run start" got the job done!